# Integrating PhonGap Api in Secha Touch 2.4.2

Tags: extjs, phonegap

Can I integrate PhoneGap api in secha touch 2.4.2 application
what is the procedure to use PhoneGap Api in Sencha Touch application ?

And after integrating api can I save camera picture (taken from device) in device storage folders

Please suggest if someone have this experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use Extjs 6 with Phonegap and so maybe is the same way.

You have to move you'r build folder to the phonegap "www" folder.
Then include this on you'r index.html :

```
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

Don't create any cordova.js file, phonegap will do for you.

For the second question, you can take picture with this plugin : https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-camera/

And store them with this option of the camera plugin : https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-camera/#camerapicturesourcetype--enum